# Integration testing authenticated network requests with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, jsdom, pollyjs

I'm trying to set up some integration tests using Jest and React testing library, but I would like to use [PollyJS](https://github.com/Netflix/pollyjs) to record and replay actual network requests via my local dev server instead of mocking. The first step would be getting my network requests working against my local dev server.

This would be pretty simple with an endpoint that is meant to be publicly consumable, meaning one does not need to login to an account in order to get an authorized response. But I've been having trouble figuring out how I can make an endpoint that requires authentication.

Here's a example test where the `POST` request is made to my login endpoint that will set a cookie with an auth token.

The component `MyDataFetchingComponent` will do a request to an endpoint that will load data only if the user is authenticated. If it is successful, the component will render `'data loaded!`.

```
import { MyDataFetchingComponent } from "../MyDataFetchingComponent";
import { render, waitForElementToBeRemoved } from "@testing-library/react";

test("render", async () => {
  await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: "myusername",
      password: "password",
    }),
    credentials: "omit",
  });

  const { getByText } = render(<MyDataFetchingComponent />);
  getByText("loading");
  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => getByText("loading"));
  getByText("data loaded!");
});
```

I thought because jest uses jsdom as its test environment, that this would behave similarly to how it does in the browser, but it doesn't seem to be the case. The data fetching request gets back a 401 error I set up if the user isn't authenticated.

Comment: Are you saying that executing this test you get a 401 error ? Because Jest runs in Node, which does not come with an implementation of the fetch API. Do you have an external module which implements fetch that cannot be seen in above code ?

Comment: @Florian Yeah, I'm using whatwg-fetch in this instance